# Is there a way to print this once every minute? I'm not to sure and I'd rather not search it up to get me confused

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat

Im not sure how to print this statement every minute, or a certain time limit. I wanted to search about it online but I thought people on SO were more relevant.

I have no idea in what to do lol

```
import time
while True:

    print("This prints once a minute.")

    time.sleep
```

I want it to print every second or minute

Comment: Use `time.sleep(60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a time value after the time.sleep
Since you want to print that every minute, and a minute has 60 seconds,

your code would be:

```
time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there

change time.sleep to

```
time.sleep(10)
```

That will sleep 10 seconds.

Comment: the OP asked for 60 seconds, not 10 seconds. I assume that is why you're answer was not accepted

Comment: LOL them's the breaks :)